# Workings for addition calculator is not showing

Tags: python, math, calculator, addition

```
print ("Naomi's Calculator!")

print("Addition")

value_1= 10
value_2= 15
working= (value_1 "+" value_2)
print(working)

result=(value_1+value_2)
print(result)
```

working variable is wrong, i want the result to be like 10+15

Comment: Use + not "+" inside working

Comment: Do you mean you expected the result to be a string `'10+15'`?

Comment: yes!! i want it to show 10+15

Comment: Use f-string `working = f'{value_1} + {value_2}'`

Comment: ```working= (value_1 "+" value_2)```, this line will raise the error, it is not separated.

Answer (score 0):

`value_1` and `value_2` are `int`, you need to convert them in string if you want to see that output for working variable.

```
working = (str(value_1)+"+" +str(value_2))
```

Comment: woah, thanks, it works! i havent learnt this one hahah